# have gdb read automatically ./.gdbinit

Tags: linux, gdb

With the pristine `gdb (Debian 8.2.1-2)` while debugging RefPerSys (GPLv3+, on [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/bstarynk/refpersys)) commit [ec4ab756d302056cace0b](https://gitlab.com/bstarynk/refpersys/commit/ec4ab756d302056cace0b68ddbac8abfae20e985) on my Linux/x86-64/Debian Sid AMD2970WX desktop, I am reproducibly getting

```
rimski.x86_64 ~/refpersys 14:39 .0 % gdb --args ./refpersys --object-tinybenchmark1
GNU gdb (Debian 8.2.1-2) 8.2.1
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./refpersys...done.
warning: File "/home/basile/refpersys/.gdbinit" auto-loading has been declined by your `auto-load safe-path' set to "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".
To enable execution of this file add
    add-auto-load-safe-path /home/basile/refpersys/.gdbinit
line to your configuration file "/home/basile/.gdbinit".
To completely disable this security protection add
    set auto-load safe-path /
line to your configuration file "/home/basile/.gdbinit".
For more information about this security protection see the
"Auto-loading safe path" section in the GDB manual.  E.g., run from the shell:
    info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path"
```

What is the magic to have my [`./.gdbinit`](https://gitlab.com/bstarynk/refpersys/blob/master/.gdbinit) digested by such a `gdb` invocation without diagnostics? That  `.gdbinit`  contains:

```
# file refpersys/.gdbinit 
# GPLv3+ licensed 
add-auto-load-safe-path ./.gdbinit 
break abort 
break rps_fatal_stop_at 
set max-value-size 67108864
```

I could (and did that in the past) rebuild `gdb` from its source code. But today, I am lame, and prefer focusing on my bugs.

FWIW

```
(gdb) show configuration 
This GDB was configured as follows:
   configure --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
             --with-auto-load-dir=$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load
             --with-auto-load-safe-path=$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load
             --with-expat
             --with-gdb-datadir=/usr/share/gdb (relocatable)
             --with-jit-reader-dir=/usr/lib/gdb (relocatable)
             --without-libunwind-ia64
             --with-lzma
             --with-babeltrace
             --with-intel-pt
             --disable-libmcheck
             --without-mpfr
             --with-python=/usr (relocatable)
             --without-guile
             --with-separate-debug-dir=/usr/lib/debug (relocatable)
             --with-system-gdbinit=/etc/gdb/gdbinit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as the warning says when you launch gdb:

```
To enable execution of this file add
    add-auto-load-safe-path /home/basile/refpersys/.gdbinit
line to your configuration file "/home/basile/.gdbinit".
```

It seems like you've misunderstood and added the line into the .gdbinit file within your repo but it needs to go into your home directory.

If the .gdbinit file doesn't yet exist in your home directory, you can create it and only add the needed line above, and it should work.

Comment: I am having this problem years later, on Windows.. .gdbinit file in my Home directory has suggested add-... command but it still fails to load local gdbinit